# feeding scaled down voltage to XADC (Xilinx)

Tags: resistors, adc, dc-dc-converter, scaling, load-regulation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYx9PO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have XADC (Xilinx) with single ended voltage range of 0-1V. To regulate the output of a DC/DC converter let's say 15V i feed the XADC with 15V scaled down by ratio of 1/16, So using 150K(1%) and 10K(0.01%) resistor. The worst case error would be around 0.103%. That looks very small. Now lets say i want to maintain the regulation to 15V +/-5%. I wanted to understand how would the scaling down of voltage for feedback would affect the voltage regulation in DC converter? What would be better option either to scale down and feedback or to use separate ADC with higher input range ? What else to consider ? Thanks

Comment: Draw a circuit, ditch the words.

Comment: Show your math, too. How did you get 0.103% error out of 1% resistors?

Comment: mybad it's 0.01% tolerance for 10K and 1% for 150K...formula used {{10K/(10K+150K)-(10K-0.01%/(10K-0.01%+150K+1%))}/(10K/(10K+150K))}*100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the circuitry or the choice of an ADC, at the end of the day you will be left with an **integer** digital value from the ADC.

You are responsible for understanding how that integer corresponds to the voltage at the input. Then you have to design your feedback algorithms taking the conversion factor into account.

If you are worried about the stability of your feedback algorithm then you should be looking at the resolution, linearity, and accuracy of whatever ADC you use.

Comment: I get the algorithm part but I wanted to understand the relationship between granuality and regulation from the circuit point of view as due to scaling I guess the transient response of converter would suffer...

Comment: No, I think you are missing the point. The analog scaling you did with the voltage divider can be exactly reversed by multiplying the digital  ADC output by 16....it does not **inherently** have any affect at all on the overall behavior of your system.

Comment: Ok then what about the resistor tolerance variation does that become insignificant? since I have 0-1V ADC input range I was worried about overall error creeping in, as a good percentage of the actual input signal before my regulation algorithm takes over.

Comment: The relative importance of resistor matching can not be discussed until you provide the resolution, linearity, and accuracy specifications of the ADC(s). If this is a one-off (not mass production) then you can easily measure the actual voltage divider ratio and add that factor to your math.